# Not able to update the values in jscon file -jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to update this json file:

```js
{
  "name": "abc",
  "age": "123",
  "project-name": "Test",
  "city": "pune",
  "project-git": "Test",
  "notification": {
    "email-subject": "Test"
  }
}
```

I am trying to change `project-name` and `email-subject` to some other value.

The code to change `email-subject` is as follows:

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
File jsonFile = new File("abc.json");

JsonNode root = objectMapper.readTree(jsonFile);
JsonNode steps = root.get("notification");


for (final JsonNode item: steps) {
    if (item.findPath("email-subject") != null) {
        ((ObjectNode) item).put("email-subject", "Test update");
    }
}

String resultJson = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(root);
```

And the code to update `project-name` is as follows:

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
File jsonFile = new File("bac.json");

JsonNode root = objectMapper.readTree(jsonFile);

((ObjectNode) item).put("project-name", "update name")
objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(root);
```

In both cases, I am getting this exception:

```
Error : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.TextNode cannot be cast to com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The reason why you are getting the exception is that your `item` variable is apparently of type `TextNode`, but you are trying to cast (convert) it to an `ObjectNode`, which isn't possible. Try to change the `(ObjectNode)` in front of your `item` variable to `(TextNode)` and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ... after changing the ((TextNode) item).put("email-subject", "Test update");  --  Error -->  The method put(String, String) is undefined for the type TextNode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`notification` is an objectNode. You can access its fields directly.

```
JsonNode root = objectMapper.readTree(jsonFile);
JsonNode steps = root.get("notification");

((ObjectNode) root).put("project-name", "update name");
if (((ObjectNode) steps).has("email-subject")) {
    ((ObjectNode) steps).put("email-subject", "Test update");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer its working... values are getting updated in the file but is does not get updated in the file with same format as input  format ...  jscon updated in file in a line : {"name": "abc","age": "123","project-name": "Test","city": "pune", "project-git": "Test", "notification": { "email-subject": "Test" }}

Comment: code use for above comment.....String resultJson = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(root);
    
    JsonNode actualObj = objectMapper.readTree(resultJson);
    
    objectMapper.writeValue(jsonFile, actualObj); ...  Appreciate ur help

Comment: What is the purpose of creating `actualObj`?  Try to write the `root` directly to the file.  `objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(jsonFile, root);`